# Using batch to find data in .csv and use output to continue batch

Tags: excel, csv, find

I use a batch to retrieve the first two letters of the computer name (e.g. 'NL') and set it as `%country%`.

What I would like to do is use `%country%` to search in a .csv file in column A (eg 'A7'). When the batch has found the information, it has to return it from column B (eg 'B7') and set it to `%adv%`.

```
@echo off

:HOME
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set CSVFILE=C:\Users\username\Desktop\test2.csv
set COUNTRY=%computername:~0,2%

:FINDIT
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (%CSVFILE%) do (
   set inline=%%A
   for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%1 in ("!inline!") do (
      set "Area=%%~1" & set "adv=%%~2" 
      GOTO :SHOWRES
   )
)

:SHOWRES
echo %adv%
pause
```